# Paginador con formato << 1 2 3 >>

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hola estoy usando el paginador de django 1.8 (paginator) me funciona bien, pero quisiera que me mostrara el numero de mis paginas de esta forma

tengo 21 registros eso quiere decir decir que tengo 3 paginas y el paginador deberia mostrar:

<< 1 2 3 >>

pero me muestra
<< 1 >>

hago click en siguien de cambia a 2, no se si hay una forma de que me muestre de lso 3 las 3 paginas y cuando yo haga click en cual quiera de las paginas me lleve a esa paginas, espero me deje entender  aqui les dejo el codigo
esperando su pronta ayuda, gracias

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

class ListarTipoAlmacen(ListView):
model = Tipo_almacen
template_name = 'tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html'
paginate_by = 10

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListarTipoAlmacen, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    lista_tipo_almacen =      Tipo_almacen.objects.all().order_by('descripcion')
    paginator = Paginator(lista_tipo_almacen, self.paginate_by)

    page = self.request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        tipo_almacen = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        tipo_almacen = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        tipo_almacen = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['lista_tipo_almacen']= tipo_almacen
    return context
```

LISTA.HTML

```
introducir el código aquí
<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Lista de Tipo de almacen</h4>
        </div>

        <table class="table">
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
            <tbody>
                {% for data in lista_tipo_almacen %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{data.descripcion}}
                        <td>

                            <a href="{% url 'editar_tipo_almacen' data.pk %}">Editar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                            <a href="{% url 'eliminar-tipo-almacen' data.pk %}" data-toggle="modal_almacen" data-target="#modal_almacen" data-id="{{ data.descripcion }}">Eliminar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

 {% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="">
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"> << </a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}


            <li class="active">
                <span> {{ page_obj.number }} de {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }} </span>
            </li>


        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li>
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"> >> </a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
        {% else %}
            <h3>Your File Exam</h3>
            <p>No hay registros para cargar</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Estimado, deberías cerrar todas tus preguntas anteriores. Alguna de elllas ya ha sido solucionada?

Comment: Cesar como cierro mis otras preguntas anteriores ?

Comment: En la parte izquierda de cada respuesta puedes darle tu voto o marcarla como la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la respuesta:

Lista.html

```
<ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="">
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"> << </a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}


        {% for num in paginator.page_range %}

                <li class="activate">
                    <span> <a href="?q={{ context }}&page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a> </span>
                </li>

        {% endfor %}


        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li>
                <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"> >> </a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>í
```

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.